# null pointer exception in java poi?

Tags: java, apache-poi

```
for (int j=0; j< sheet1.getLastRowNum() + 1; j++) {
  Row row = sheet1.getRow(j);
  Cell cell = row.getCell(0);
  System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());
}
```

line number 3: `Cell cell = row.getCell(0);`

Answer (score 3):

`getLastRowNum()` is zero index based, so only `j <sheet1.getLastRowNum()` is sufficient. When you are adding 1 it exceeds the limit and pointing a row, which is not initialized, so it is causing `nullpointerexception`.

for detail check [here](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html)